# Get current line of a file that is piped to a command

Tags: linux, bash, unix, pipe, cat

My goal is to figure out a PIN password for a daemon listening at port 30002.
So I created a dictionary called pinlist and i pipe it to nc (netcat) localhost 30002

This is the command:
cat pinlist | nc localhost 30002

It works, I get in, but the problem is - I don't know which PIN was the one that did it.
I imagine I should somehow echo that last accessed line of the file 'pinlist', but how?
E.g: cat pinlist | nc localhost 30002 && echo [current line in pinlist] #this would print each line in pinlist

Answer (score 0):

```
cat -n pinlist
```

also shows the line numbers